# Select2 - Disable Search Term Matches Text Underline

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 v3.5.2, when we type on the search box, the matches text will be underlined as shown below.

[image]

How do I disable this underline feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Following CSS

```
.select2-result-selectable .select2-match,
.select2-result-unselectable .select2-match {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

or remove line `657-660` from `3.5.2/select2.css`

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine format function in options:

```
$el.select2({
    formatResult: function(result, container, query, escapeMarkup) {
        return escapeMarkup(result.text);
    }
});
```